# Very slow query when filtering

Tags: plsql, yii2, sql-optimization

I have a table INVESTOR_OPPORTUNITY which is structured as follows:

```
- ID        // PRIMARY KEY
- INVESTOR_ID
- OPPORTUNITY_ID
- POINTS    // values 0 to 5
```

An INVESTOR can be associated with the same opportunity multiple times and there are typically 10,000 investors per opportunity. So, on average there are about 20,000 rows per opportunity.

In my GridView, I need to display one row per investor with a count of the opportunities scored 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. Something like this:

```
INVESTOR_ID    |  count of 1pt  | count of 2pt | etc
123456         |        7       |       13     | etc
```

Here is the main part of the query:

```
        ->select([
            'INVESTOR_ID',
            'SUM( CASE WHEN OPP.POINTS=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS countPoints0',
            'SUM( CASE WHEN OPP.POINTS=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS countPoints1',
            'SUM( CASE WHEN OPP.POINTS=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS countPoints2',
            'SUM( CASE WHEN OPP.POINTS=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS countPoints3',
            'SUM( CASE WHEN OPP.POINTS=4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS countPoints4',
            'SUM( CASE WHEN OPP.POINTS=5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS countPoints5',
        ])
        ->andWhere([OPPORTUNITY_ID=>$this->OPPORTUNITY_ID])
        ->groupBy(['INVESTOR_ID']);
```

This tends to work fine and is fairly fast. However, as soon as I filter for a value in one of the counts the query can take more than 17 seconds and sometimes upwards of one or two minutes!

For example: if I want to see all investors who have more than 1 opportunity with zero points:

```
        ->select([
            'INVESTOR_ID',
            'SUM( CASE WHEN OPP.POINTS=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS countPoints0',
            'SUM( CASE WHEN OPP.POINTS=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS countPoints1',
            'SUM( CASE WHEN OPP.POINTS=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS countPoints2',
            'SUM( CASE WHEN OPP.POINTS=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS countPoints3',
            'SUM( CASE WHEN OPP.POINTS=4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS countPoints4',
            'SUM( CASE WHEN OPP.POINTS=5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS countPoints5',
        ])
        ->having('SUM( CASE WHEN OPP.POINTS=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >1')
        ->andWhere([OPPORTUNITY_ID=>$this->OPPORTUNITY_ID])
        ->groupBy(['INVESTOR_ID']);
```

I have tried a combination of indexes (INVESTOR_ID : OPPORTUNITY_ID : POINTS) but no luck.

How can I optimise this query??

Any help appreciated.

Comment: first how many rows you have before filtering with having clause ??  second you are using activerecord??  show the rest of the query code

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe you could replace `having` with `andWhere(['OPP.POINTS' => 0])`? Result should be the same but you can use index now. IMHO you would be better with 5 columns with 0/1 values for points instead of one column that you need to processed every time.

Comment: @Bizley that won't give same result, because if you use andWhere like that the rows with different value in `OPP.POINTS` would be filterede before `GROUP BY` so countPoints1 - countpoints5 would be always empty. But it can be used in subquery like `$subquery = ... ->select(['INVESTOR_ID'])->where(['OPP.POINTS' => 0, 'OPPORTUNITY_ID' => $this->OPPORTUNITY_ID])` then use this subquery in main query `->andWhere(['IN', 'INVESTOR_ID', $subquery])` instead of having. That would allow use of indexes.

Comment: @MichalHynčica yeah, you're right. I would still go with 5 columns instead of one.

Comment: @scaisEdge Yes I am using activeRecord. What is the best alternative?

Comment: @MichalHynčica The query on this page is actually a subquery exactly as you describe. I have tried both "having" on the subquery and "andWhere" on the parent query. It is hard to tell which is faster. Which would be the best approach?

Comment: @Bizley Good idea. I will create five columns instead

Comment: All: So I found one issue: The production server did not have the same indexes as the dev server! Fixed! But I still need to do whatever I can to strip out each second. The query is still in the order of 6 seconds under load.

Comment: @DrBorrow `HAVING` cannot use any indexes because it's applied to the grouped results where no indexes are built so subquery should be faster than having. I'm using slightly different approach in cases like this. I would make an extra table for results of calculations, stored procedure to calculate countPoints for given investor_id and oportunity_id and save them to extra table. Then set the triggers on main table update/insert/delete to call the stored procedure to recount data for investor_id, oportunity_id pairs that has been changed.

Comment: @MichalHynčica thank you - I will go with the subquery and I really like the idea of the stored procedure... very good idea. Thanks both for your help.